# malloc. overcommit. macOS

Tags: c++, память, macos, ос, malloc

решил проверить, сколько динамической памяти выделит mac под программу. написал примерно так:

```
char* array = new int[100]; //сотню здесь увеличивал
if (array == null) std::cout << "OS didn't gave memory.";
```

параллельно открыл activity monitor, чтобы отслеживать кол-во используемой процессом памяти.
очень смутило, что мне дали 50гб...
В итоге дошел до overcommit(a) - памяти тебе могут "выделить" очень много, но когда дело доходит до её инициализации... ядро просто убивает процесс.
в итоге вопросы:
как мне отключить overcommit(извините за уродскую формулировку)? к чему это приведет? т.е. при запросе памяти в 100гб мне просто в

```
char* array
```

положат ноль? (хочу именно такой результат!).
Нашел похожий вопрос в инете, там был файл и конкретная строка, в которой надо просто флажок поменять, но речь там шла о линуксе + советовали этого не делать.

Comment: http://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html - здесь я прочитал про overcommit

Comment: По стандарту - не положат 0, а сгенерируют исключение :) Для этого надо использовать `new(std::nothrow)`...